# JavaScript date throws Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, validation, date, undefined

i am trying to compare two dates `from date and to date` following is my method :

```
function isValidDate() {
        var fromDate ="";
        var toDate ="";

        var fromDateTemp = $("#fromRequestDate").val(); //2013-12-05
        var toDateTemp = $("#toRequestDate").val(); //2013-12-01

        if(fromDateTemp.length != '0' && toDateTemp.length != '0'){
            fromDate = new Date(fromDateTemp);
            toDate = new Date(toDateTemp);
        }

        if (fromDate.length != '0' || toDate.length != '0') {
            $("#validationMessage").text("Please Select From Date and To Date");
            return false;

        } else if (fromDate.getDate() > toDate.getDate()) {
            $("#validationMessage").text("From Date is greater than To Date");
            return false;

        } else {
            $("#validationMessage").text("");
            return true;

        }
    }
```

but i get `Ivalid Date` as well as `undefined` when calculating length.

so please help me to find the issue.

Thanks

Comment: `fromDateTemp.length != '0'` Don't compare integers and strings. Just compare directly against integer `0`. And we can't possible help you if you don't tell use the value being passed to `Date()`. You could be passing anything in there, how can we guess what kind of value might be causing the problem?

Comment: @meagar please have look at the sample values i have edited with the questions, what will happen if `$("#fromRequestDate").val()` has no value ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's corrected js:

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzCtB)

```
function isValidDate() {
        var fromDate = null;
        var toDate = null;

        var fromDateTemp = $("#fromRequestDate").val();
        var toDateTemp = $("#toRequestDate").val();

        if(fromDateTemp.length != 0 && toDateTemp.length != 0){
            fromDate = new Date(fromDateTemp);
            toDate = new Date(toDateTemp);
        }

        if (fromDate == null || toDate == null) {
            $("#validationMessage").text("Please Select From Date and To Date");
            return false;

        } else if (fromDate.getTime() > toDate.getTime()) {
            $("#validationMessage").text("From Date is greater than To Date");
            return false;

        } else {
            $("#validationMessage").text("");
            return true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it did what i wanted. +1. Thanks for saving my time

Answer (score 2):

We usually compare two Dates using `getTime` (it returns the number of milliseconds passed since 1970)

So,

```
fromDate.getTime() > toDate.getTime()
```

ought to work. Assuming, of course, that the values being taken from the #fromReqDate and #toReqDate are instances of `Date` (simple check `fromDate instanceOf Date` should return `true`)

Answer (score 2):

I think mistake is in your condition checking `if (fromDate.length == '0' || toDate.length == '0')` instead of this you used `if(fromDateTemp.length != '0' && toDateTemp.length != '0')` check the code and revert if you are facing issue still.

```
var fromDate ="";
var toDate ="";

var fromDateTemp = '2013-12-05'; //2013-12-05
var toDateTemp = '2013-12-01'; //2013-12-01

if(fromDateTemp.length != '0' && toDateTemp.length != '0'){
    fromDate = new Date(fromDateTemp);
    toDate = new Date(toDateTemp);
}

if (fromDate.length == '0' || toDate.length == '0') {
   alert("Please Select From Date and To Date");
    return false;

} else if (fromDate.getDate() > toDate.getDate()) {
    alert("From Date is greater than To Date");
    return false;

} else {
    alert("");
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this.

```
if(isNaN(new Date(fromDateTemp)))
{
    alert("Please enter a valid from date");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var fromDateTemp = $("#fromRequestDate").val(); //2013-12-05
var toDateTemp = $("#toRequestDate").val(); //2013-12-01
```

instead of these two code just replace the following codes

```
var fromDateTemp = new Date(''+$("#fromRequestDate").val()); //2013-12-05
var toDateTemp = new Date(''+$("#toRequestDate").val()); //2013-12-01
```